# How can I pass an interpolation into child component?

Tags: angular, components, interpolation

I am looping `<td>` tag like this:

```
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow, index as i">
            <td class="name-column">{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td class="date-column">{{ item.date | datepipe: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I want to make the `<tbody>` as a child component and pass its interpolation from the parent component because this table is used across multiple pages in my app. My question is, can I pass the interpolation from parent into the child component so maybe the code will look like this?

parent-component.ts:

```
  public tabledata = [
    {
      value: `{{ item.name }}`, style: /* some style */
    },
    {
      value: `{{ item.date | datepipe: 'dd/MM/yyyy }}`, style: /* some style */
    }
  ];
```

child-component.html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow, index as i">
    <td *ngFor="let val of tableData"
      [ngStyle]="val.style">
      <!-- put the interpolation here, can I use val.value? --></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried using `[innerHTML]` but it still just rendering normal string. How can I achieve that condition, or is there another approach to achieve that?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but you can decorate your "child" component's properties with `@Input()` and then pass values to those properties when you create them with your HTML directive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can pass whatever you'd like into a child component using @Input.
However, to make the table truly reusable I would recommend something like this:

In the Child (table) component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    template: 
    `
            <tr *ngFor="let row of data.rows">
                <td *ngFor="let val of row.values" [style]="val.style">
                    {{ val.value }}
                </td>
            </tr>
    `
})

export class DataTableComponent {
    @Input data: IStyledValuesCollection;

}

export interface IStyledValuesCollection {
    public IStyledValuesRow[] rows;
}

export interface IStyledValuesRow {
    public IStyledValue[] values;
}

export interface IStyledValue {
    public String value;
    public String style;
}
```

Then, in the parent component html file:

```
.
.
.
<app-data-table [data]="yourData"></app-data-table>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The interpolation itself is a string. So if you try to render that, it will just give you the string itself. It will not evaluate the interpolation. [Interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions) is used to evaluate strings and template expressions in your HTML. `[innerHTML]` will not work because it simply is not "HTML".

I'm not sure why you would want to pass the interpolated string in the first place. You need to use interpolation to display the values in the template of your child component. Your dataset also seems to be incorrect. You need to pass an array for `ngFor`. Your second `ngFor` on the other hand is trying to loop over an object.

Here's how it should look.

**parent-component.ts**

```
public tabledata = [
    {
      item: item, style: /* some style */
    },
    {
      item: item2, style: /* some style */
    }
];
```

**child-component.html**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData, index as i">
    <td class="name-column">{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td class="date-column">{{ item.date | datepipe: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I haven't added the styles because I'm not sure where exactly you want them. Let me know where you want them and I shall update the answer.